# H2 database: prevent users from dumping database content (SCRIPT, BACKUP, etc)

Tags: java, security, h2

We are using Java + H2 Database in server mode, because we do not want users from accessing database file.

All database users created by admin are regular users (not admin). Is there any other possibilities for those regular users to get the database content? I have tried SCRIPT and BACKUP command, and failed because they require admin privilege. That's nice :)

Is making users not admin is enough to protect users from dumping database content?

More, is making application user = database user, a good security practise? Previously, for authentication, we use custom 'users' table in the database, not the database user.

Thank you.

Comment: As this is a possible duplicate of [H2 database: how to protect with encryption, without exposing file encryption key](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6148415/h2-database-how-to-protect-with-encryption-without-exposing-file-encryption-key), please update your original question.

Comment: This is not a duplicate. This question is about securing the database content from dumping by regular user, once the user has logged on to the H2 console. Plus, i also asking about programming practice that using database users as application users. The other question (linked) is about hiding encryption key.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any other possibilities for those regular users to get the database content?

No. That's the point of database users and rights, so that a user can only access the data he is allowed to.

> Is making users not admin is enough to protect users from dumping database content?

Yes.

> is making application user = database user, a good security practise?

Yes, if the client application has access to the database (over TCP/IP).

> Previously, for authentication, we use custom 'users' table in the database, not the database user.

This is a common solution for web applications and other 3-tier systems (where the user doesn't have access to the database).

Comment: Is it possible to prevent regular user from accessing information_schema?

Comment: Hm, regular users should have no or only limited access to the information_schema... I see currently they have full read access. This is not good, I will try to fix that. There is currently no way to prevent users to access the tables.